# Can't create a Hippocms project

Tags: java, hippocms

I am trying to make a new project on Hippocms. I have followed the steps from the onehippo web page. I have downloaded Maven seperately. I have removed all the metadatas from other projects, but it keeps showing me the same error when I ran mvn clean verify. I have deleted the repository multiple times
and I still got this message. The problem is that there are not any solutions on the Internet especially for Hippo.
[Hippo Errors][1].

```
  C:\Users\Administrator\myhippoproject>mvn clean verify
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] My Hippo Project
    [INFO] My Hippo Project Repository Data
    [INFO] My Hippo Project Repository Data For Application
    [INFO] My Hippo Project Repository Data For Development
    [INFO] My Hippo Project Site
    [INFO] My Hippo Project Repository Data Web Files
    [INFO] My Hippo Project CMS
    [INFO] My Hippo Project Essentials
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building My Hippo Project 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ myhippoproject ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven-versions) @ 
    myhippoproject ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:regex-property (property-
    commandline-offline) @ myhippoproject ---
    [INFO] No match to regex '"true"' found in '"false"'. The initial value 
    '"false"' is left as-is...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:regex-property (property-
    commandline-online) @ myhippoproject ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ 
    myhippoproject ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources-no-fork) @ 
    myhippoproject ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---
    [INFO] Building My Hippo Project Repository Data 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ myhippoproject-
    repository-data ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven-versions) @ 
    myhippoproject-repository-data ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:regex-property (property-
    commandline-offline) @ myhippoproject-repository-data ---
    [INFO] No match to regex '"true"' found in '"false"'. The initial value 
    '"false"' is left as-is...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:regex-property (property-
    commandline-online) @ myhippoproject-repository-data ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ 
    myhippoproject-repository-data ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources-no-fork) @ 
    myhippoproject-repository-data ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---
    [INFO] Building My Hippo Project Repository Data For Application 0.1.0-
    SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ myhippoproject-
   repository-data-application ---
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven-versions) @ 
   myhippoproject-repository-data-application ---
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:regex-property (property-
   commandline-offline) @ myhippoproject-repository-data-application ---
   [INFO] No match to regex '"true"' found in '"false"'. The initial value 
   '"false"' is left as-is...
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:regex-property (property-
   commandline-online) @ myhippoproject-repository-data-application ---
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) @ myhippoproject-
   repository-data-application ---
   [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --verify HEAD"
   [INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\Administrator\myhippoproject\repository-
   data\application
   [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   --
   [INFO] Reactor Summary:
   [INFO]
   [INFO] My Hippo Project ................................... SUCCESS [  1.328 
   s]
   [INFO] My Hippo Project Repository Data ................... SUCCESS [  0.062 
   s]
   [INFO] My Hippo Project Repository Data For Application ... FAILURE [  0.469 
    s]
   [INFO] My Hippo Project Repository Data For Development ... SKIPPED
   [INFO] My Hippo Project Site .............................. SKIPPED
   [INFO] My Hippo Project Repository Data Web Files ......... SKIPPED
   [INFO] My Hippo Project CMS ............................... SKIPPED
   [INFO] My Hippo Project Essentials ........................ SKIPPED
   [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   --
   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
   [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   --
   [INFO] Total time: 2.766 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-19T11:48:05+02:00
   [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/316M
   [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   --
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-
   plugin:1.4:create (default) on project myhippoproject-repository-data-
   application: Cannot get the revision information from the scm repository :
   [ERROR] Exception while executing SCM command.: Error while executing 
   command. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "git" (in 
   directory "C:\Users\Administrator\myhippoproject\repository-
   data\application"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file 
   specified
   [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR]
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
   switch.
   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
   [ERROR]
   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
   read the following articles:
   [ERROR] [Help 1] 
   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
   [ERROR]
   [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the 
   command
   [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :myhippoproject-repository-data-application



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Lm8.png
```

Comment: instead of adding screenshot, please add logs in the question..easy to check.

Comment: @SangamBelose I am a new user. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This has been solved for version 12.1.0. This version is as of yet unreleased. I cannot say when this will be released, but soon I expect. Alternative to installing git you can remove the "buildnumber-maven-plugin"  which is in various poms in the project. Thanks for reporting

Answer (score 2):

Your build problem seems to be related to a maven plugin that tries to execute a **git** command. See this line in your log:

```
[ERROR] Exception while executing SCM command.: Error while executing 
   command. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "git" (in 
   directory "C:\Users\Administrator\myhippoproject\repository-
   data\application"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file 
   specified
```

It seems it requires git to be installed on your system. You probably need to install **git** first and then try that build command again.

Comment: You don't need git to build Hippo. I confirmed this by uninstalling git and running mvn clean install. - edit: nevermind, this seems to be a problem in archetype 12.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need git to build Hippo, but something seems to be wrong in the 12.0.1 archetype. I will file a bug. Please install git if you can.